# Expression Tree with Property Inheritance causes an argument exception

Tags: .net, linq, expression-trees

Following this post: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937072/how-can-i-write-custom-comparison-definition-for-binary-operator-equal-for-enti) I'm trying to create an expression tree that references the property of a property. My code looks like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void X {get;set;}
}

public interface IBar : IFoo
{
    void Y {get;set;}
}

public interface IFooBarContainer
{
    IBar Bar {get;set;}
}

public class Filterer
{
     //Where T = "IFooBarContainer"
     public IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
     {
              var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "item");

              //...

               //where propertyName = "IBar.X";
               PropertyOfProperty(argument, propertyName); 
     }

        private static MemberExpression PropertyOfProperty(Expression expr, string propertyName)
        {
            return propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate<string, MemberExpression>(null, (current, property) => Expression.Property(current ?? expr, property));
        }
}
```

I receive the exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Instance
>   property 'X' is not defined for type
>   'IBar'

ReSharper turned the code in the link above into the condensed statement in my example. Both forms of the method returned the same error.

If I reference `IBar.Y` the method does not fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property you're trying to access is *not* `IBar.X`, it's `IFoo.X`. The `Expression.Property` method expects the actual type that declares the property, not a subtype. If you're not convinced, try that :

```
var prop = typeof(IBar).GetProperty("X");
```

It returns null (only because `IBar` is an interface ; it would work for a class)

I think the easiest way to make it work is to create a helper method to resolve the actual property, by walking up the type hierarchy recursively :

```
private PropertyInfo GetProperty(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (prop == null)
    {
        var baseTypesAndInterfaces = new List<Type>();
        if (type.BaseType != null) baseTypesAndInterfaces.Add(type.BaseType);
        baseTypesAndInterfaces.AddRange(type.GetInterfaces());
        foreach(Type t in baseTypesAndInterfaces)
        {
            prop = GetProperty(t, propertyName);
            if (prop != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return prop;
}
```

You can then rewrite your `PropertyOfProperty` as follows :

```
private static MemberExpression PropertyOfProperty(MemberExpression expr, string propertyName)
{
    return propertyName
               .Split('.')
               .Aggregate<string, MemberExpression>(
                   expr,
                   (current, property) =>
                       Expression.Property(
                           current,
                           GetProperty(current.Type, property)));
}
```

Comment: Thomas, sounds like a great solution! Just was wondering what 'arg' is in the reworked PropertyOfProperty method?

Comment: Yes, a bad copy/paste... just fixed it. I also simplified the code a bit by passing `expr` as the seed of the `Aggregate` method to get rid of the `??` operator,  it should have the same effect