# Expression Tree Binary Expression for an 'In' operation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an expression tree ([still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496256/expression-tree-with-property-inheritance-causes-an-argument-exception)) but getting further! I need to create a `BinaryExpression` to perform an 'In' comparison between a Member and a collection of items. Hence, the expression should return true if the member is contained within the items.

This obviously does not exist:

```
Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.In, memberExpression, constantExpression);
```

`constantExpression` is a `ConstantExpression` of type `IEnumerable<T>` while `memberExpression` is a `MemberExpression` of type `T`.

How would I create such an expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd usually use "Contains" instead - that's how you typically write a LINQ query which would map to "IN" in SQL:

```
var query = from user in db.Users
            where specialUsers.Contains(user.Name)
            select user.Id;
```

Comment: That was my first thought but I'm kind of lost on how to translate such a LINQ query into an expression tree.

Comment: @Adam: The easiest thing to do is try it :) Create an expression, then use Reflector to see what the compiler's done. Basically there'll be a call to Queryable.Where, with an expression which represents a call to `Contains` on a constant (the `specialUsers` collection here) passing in the evaluated `user.Name` as an argument.

Comment: Did not realize that LINQ compiled out that way. This should save me some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to added how I ultimately got this to work:

```
var callExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new Type[] {memberExpression.Type}, constantExpression, memberExpression);
```

Compiling and invoking the `callExpression` will yield whether or not a `memberExpression` is within the `constantExpression` collection.